# Jquery pretty checkboxes on jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I love [these](http://aaronweyenberg.com/90/pretty-checkboxes-with-jquery) pretty checkboxes:

and have implemented them in my site. Unfortunately when I try to integrate them with jquery mobile, they lose their look and feel.

as soon as I try to include

link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" /

either before or after my inline css, the effect is ruined. How can I fix this? thanks!

Comment: Can you paste some code? what theme are you using in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd prefer that a particular form control be left untouched by jQuery Mobile, simply give that element the attribute `data-role="none"`. So you have to add the attribute `data-role="none"` on the input type checkbox tag and the problem will be fixed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: A thousand and one checks to you, kind sir or madam!